# Server communication issue

Tags: android, performance

I have the following requirement:

i> An AsyncTask which fetches Paginated data , say 100 pages with 100 items each .

ii> An Intent Service which also fetches Paginated data , say 100 pages with 100 items each.

I am facing the following problem:

I have the following method getResponseFromServerGET() in class HttpCommunication which communicates with the server.

```
public String getResponseFromServerGET(String serviceUrl,
            HashMap<String, String> headerInfo) {
        String responseStr = "";
            try {
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);

            HttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet(serviceUrl);
            // Get the key value from the HashMap
            if (headerInfo != null) {
                for (String iterator : headerInfo.keySet()) {
                    mHttpGet.addHeader((String) iterator,
                            (String) headerInfo.get((String) iterator));
                }
            }
            HttpResponse mResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);
            HttpEntity mEntity = mResponse.getEntity();

            if (mEntity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = mEntity.getContent();
                responseStr = Utils.convertStreamToString(inputStream);
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return responseStr;
    }

    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            return sb.toString();
   }
```

I create two instances & call the following method from two different classes.
There is no link between the AsyncTask & IntentService .

```
HttpCommunication comm1 = new HttpCommunication();
comm1.getResponseFromServerGET(); // Passing the necessary params in IntentService


HttpCommunication comm2 = new HttpCommunication();
comm2.getResponseFromServerGET(); // Passing the necessary params in AsyncTask
```

After the response is fetched , the response is parsed from IntentService and AsyncTask by calling the respective methods in another class ParseResponse.

Sometimes the following exception is thrown while parsing the response fetched from IntentService,

**"org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object"**

This issue is occurring sometimes not always.
Can this be a HTTP issue or specifically IntentService issue where due to multiple operations of AsyncTask & IntentService , the response(JSON) from server is getting corrupted ?

I have checked the response from server log for each page but didnot find any anomaly with the response(JSON) being sent.

Any suggestions/hints will be appreciated.

Comment: do you get it at particular character??

Comment: sometimes it occurring at 8th page , maybe sometimes 10th page. Its not happening for any specific character.

Comment: Do both download the same pages from the same url? At the same time? Hmmm.. are all pages downloaded with one request? Have you checked that if you have an `Unterminated object"` you got all pages or only a part.

Comment: Is it only one character every time or are the following characters corrupted too? Do you check/record the string.length() of every response? Is it always the same? `I have checked the response from server log for each page but didnot find any anomaly` well we could conclude that the download is perfect. How can you check 100 pages? Save every response to file. Especially if there is an Unterminated object. Then later just load it from file and parse.

Comment: Do you ever have an issue when only one of them is downloading? Or didn't you test?